# Detect where ListViewItem has been clicked/pressed

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe8

In Delphi XE8 using a Firemonkey TListView.

I have a ListView with about 5 items in it. Each item has an image within them.

How would one detect when the image is clicked/pressed?.

I've been looking at the procedure:

```
OnItemClickEx
```

But I do not understand how to use it. Wasn't sure if this is what I need to use or not.

Any help would be great.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set Listview item image object properties....

```
procedure TForm1.OnFormCreate(Sender:TObject)
begin
  ListView1.ItemAppearanceObjects.ItemObjects.Image.Align :=  TListItemAlign.Leading;
  ListView1.ItemAppearanceObjects.ItemObjects.Image.VertAlign := TListItemAlign.Center;
  ListView1.ItemAppearanceObjects.ItemObjects.Image.PlaceOffset.X := 370;
end;
```

Then in the ItemClickEx procedure I did the following:

```
procedure TForm1.ListView1ItemClickEx(const Sender: TObject;
ItemIndex: Integer; const LocalClickPos: TPointF;
const ItemObject: TListItemObject);
begin
 if (LocalClickPos.X > ListView1.ItemAppearanceObjects.ItemObjects.Image.PlaceOffset.X) and
      (LocalClickPos.X < (ListView1.ItemAppearanceObjects.ItemObjects.Image.PlaceOffset.X + ListView1.ItemAppearanceObjects.ItemObjects.Image.Width)) and
      (LocalClickPos.Y > ListView1.ItemAppearanceObjects.ItemObjects.Image.PlaceOffset.Y) and
      (LocalClickPos.Y < (ListView1.ItemAppearanceObjects.ItemObjects.Image.PlaceOffset.Y + ListView1.ItemAppearanceObjects.ItemObjects.Image.Height)) then
  begin
    ShowMessage('Image Pressed!');      
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

on the ListView1ItemClickEx event add

```
 if ItemObject is TListItemImage then
    ShowMessage('Image Pressed!)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
procedure TForm1.ListView1ItemClickEx(const Sender: TObject; ItemIndex:  Integer;
  const LocalClickPos: TPointF; const ItemObject: TListItemDrawable);
begin
ShowMessage('clicked: ' + ItemObject.Name); 
// ItemObject.Name is the name of the oject that is clicked in the ListView row.

//If just looking for type of object:
if ItemObject is TListItemAccessory then ShowMessage('Acessory clicked');

if ItemObject is TListItemImage then ShowMessage('Image clicked: ' + ItemObject.Name);

if ItemObject is TListItemText then ShowMessage('text clicked');
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are allready looking at the right procedure. You have to check the class of the parameter `ItemObject` there:

```
if (ItemObject<>nil) and (ItemObject.InheritsFrom(TListItemImage)) then
    //...
```

This is the minimal example which works with RAD Studio 10.1 Berlin:

Create a new multi device application and place a `TlistView` on the main form.
Add the following event handler:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ListView1.ItemAppearance.ItemAppearance := 'ImageListItemBottomDetail';
  ListView1.Items.Add;
end;

procedure TForm1.ListView1ItemClickEx(const Sender: TObject; ItemIndex:  Integer;
  const LocalClickPos: TPointF; const ItemObject: TListItemDrawable);
begin
  if (ItemObject<>nil) and (ItemObject.InheritsFrom(TListItemImage)) then
    ShowMessage('image clicked');
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I have just tried that and I still don't get any response. After 'then' I put in a ShowMessage dialog box with a test message but that doesnt appear. I tested this on windows and android.

Comment: Did you set the property `ItemAppearance` to `'ImageListItem'` or something similar?

Comment: Its set to 'ImageListItemBottomDetail'

Comment: I think this is an XE8 issue/bug. I've created a new test app and done what you have suggested, I still don't get a response when clicking the image. Bit of a pain to be honest!

Comment: Perhaps something could be done with the LocalClickPos parameter?

Comment: I think that sould be possible

Answer (score 0):

```
procedure TfmReference.ListView1UpdateObjects(const Sender: TObject;
 const AItem: TListViewItem);
begin
 AItem.Objects.FindObjectT<TListItemImage>('Image4').Bitmap := ImageList1.Source.Items[0].MultiResBitmap[0].Bitmap;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
procedure TForm1.ListView1ItemClickEx(const Sender: TObject; ItemIndex: Integer;
   const LocalClickPos: TPointF; const ItemObject: TListItemDrawable);
begin
if TListView(sender).Selected <> nil then
begin
    if ItemObject is TListItemImage then
    begin
      if TListItemImage(ItemObject).Name = 'Image3' then
        begin
          TabControl1.ActiveTab := TabItem2;
        end;
     end;
 end;
```