# How to detect click on an accessory object on tlistview on delphi android?

Tags: firemonkey, tlistview

i have populate a Tlistview in delphi android like this

```
procedure Tform1.PopulateList;
var LItem: TListViewItem;
begin
ListView1.beginUpdate;
ListView1.items.clear;

   LItem := ListView1.Items.Add;
   LItem.Index:=0;
   LItem.Text := 'My text here';
   LItem.Accessory:=TAccessoryType.Detail;
   LItem.Detail:='My details here';

ListView1.endUpdate;
end;
```

How can i detect when user clicks on The accesory image ?
there a function OnItemClickEx but i dont know how to check for user click there.

I find it googling.

```
if ItemObject is TListItemAccessory then ShowMessage('Acessory clicked');
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39099708/detect-where-listviewitem-has-been-clicked-pressed